# How to handle field with multiple possible types

Tags: jsonschema2pojo

Is there a better way to handle a field whose value could be different types in jsonschema2pojo rather than having that field generated as `java.lang.Object` (this is all caused by legacy data that can't be migrated)

For instance, if I have these JSON:

- "foo" is String

```json
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

- "foo" is Array

```json
{
  "foo": ["bar", "baz"]
}
```

I've tried declaring "type" as either a "string" or "array" in hopes the deserialization would somehow be smart enough to transform the value or force cast to either one (didn't work):

```json
{
  "type":"object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "type":"object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "type": "array"
    }
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "existingJavaType": "java.util.List<String>"
    }
  }
}
```

How would you recommend I handle this situation? Do I have no choice but to declare "foo" as an Object.

```json
{
  "type":"object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      
    }
  }
}
```

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"foo"
})
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

@JsonProperty("foo")
public Object foo;

}
```

I know I could define a second class that handle the logic for casting Object but I'd like to avoid that if possible. Such as:

```java
public class Test extends Example {

  @Override
  public List<String> getFoo(){
   // if this.foo instanceof string return List<String>
   // else return this.foo
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use Object type and use instanceOf keyword for checking the datatype of the object, once known the type you can use it accordingly. Check the example below:

```
public void set(final String key, final Object value) {
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPreferences.edit();
    if (value instanceof String) {
        editor.putString(key, (String) value);
        editor.commit();
    } else if (value instanceof Float) {
        final Float objFloat = (Float) value;
        editor.putFloat(key, objFloat.floatValue());
        editor.commit();
    } else if (value instanceof Long) {
        final Long objFloat = (Long) value;
        editor.putLong(key, objFloat.longValue());
        editor.commit();
    } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
        final Integer objFloat = (Integer) value;
        editor.putInt(key, objFloat.intValue());
        editor.commit();
    } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
        final Boolean objFloat = (Boolean) value;
        editor.putBoolean(key, objFloat.booleanValue());
        editor.commit();
    }else if (value instanceof Double) {
        editor.putLong(key, Double.doubleToRawLongBits((Double)value));
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```